# Ionic Angular - Dynamic icon selection

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

My team and I are working on an app, Written in Ionic Angular which presents calendar events.
We would like to add a small icon next to the event, which will represent the event topic-
for example, if the event is a birthday we decided to put a small cake next to it.
This is the idea we came with:

```
determineIcon(calendarEvent) {
    if(this.stringIncludes(calendarEvent.subject, "Birthday")) {
      calendarEvent.iconName = "gift";
      return;
    }
    if(this.stringIncludes(calendarEvent.subject, "Meeting")) {
      calendarEvent.iconName = "people"
    }
}

stringIncludes(calendarEventSubject, word) {
    if(calendarEventSubject.toLowerCase().includes(word.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
}
```

But this way seems too lazy, as if we want to add another icon, we need to add another keyword.
I've come here for ideas, perhaps to make this function smarter? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is probably a pretty dangerous way of doing it.. performance wise it’s pretty bad as well. Add a console.log in that function and you can probably see what I mean.. Can you not simply solve this purely in css and a class in your template? If you then add a new event, you just have to add a new icon to your css..

Comment: @MikeOne IoniCons is a built in library, so we are not adding any new icons, We are basing it off existing icons. The only problem is that when we want to implement such thing, we need to check for keywords. I know that performance-wise this function is bad. This is why I asked for ideas :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably best to do that checking for keywords purely inside your template. Or create an additional css file that translates the keywords to the ionicons.. almost any solution is better than a method call in your template 

Comment: Almost sure you can replace all the logic inside `stringIncludes` for a more performant way using regex: `return new RegExp(word,'i').test(calendarEventSubject);`. I said "Almost sure" because I really didn't test the performace.

Comment: @MikeOne This method is quite similar to one strategy we thought of, including a hard coded JSON file which will contain keywords including groups of words - for example, "people" icon will appear when the subject contains the words "meeting", "meetup" etc.

Comment: What about an extra attribute on calendarEvent? If you had a icon object you could send in icon information, complex if necessary. `calendarEvent.iconInfo` wouldn't solve your problem?

Comment: @julianobrasil Thanks for your help but currently we are focusing more on how to implement the icon logic rather then performance on testing the words :)

Comment: @julianobrasil CalendarEvent is an external object from the Outlook mail API, which does not contain any indication for the type of icon that should appear

Comment: Without an external service or, alternatively, hardcoding everything in a file, I think it's not possible to get the flexibility you're looking for.

Comment: If (calender.....includes(word.tolowercase()) === true ) { and here you launch a switch case and on case put calenderevent.iconname = case condition }